# Memory leak in gridadapter cannot find where? and how can i improve my logic to avoid GC calls?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-memory

**How can i improve my logic to reduce memory consumption and fast UI as it lags while scrolling because of GC call.**

**I user Eclipse MAT and found 3 suspects :**

**Problem Suspect 1**

One instance of "android.graphics.Bitmap" loaded by "" occupies 500,464 (14.70%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "".

**Problem Suspect 2**

2,906 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by "" occupy 1,121,048 (32.92%) bytes.

Biggest instances:

```
•class android.text.Html$HtmlParser @ 0xb4ef4448 - 126,720 (3.72%) bytes. 
•class org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services @ 0xb4ee7b48 - 80,120 (2.35%) bytes. 
•class libcore.icu.TimeZones @ 0xb4e0d2b0 - 69,144 (2.03%) bytes. 
•class java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference @ 0xb4e07ef0 - 59,080 (1.74%) bytes. 
•class com.android.internal.R$styleable @ 0xb4e2ddd0 - 57,192 (1.68%) bytes. 
•class android.R$styleable @ 0xb4e74e78 - 52,896 (1.55%) bytes. 
•class android.view.View @ 0xb4e2c228 - 46,344 (1.36%) bytes.
```

**Problem Suspect 3**

8,040 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "" occupy 514,408 (15.11%) bytes.

**My Adapter Code**

---

```
public class SomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private static int objectCounter;
    private static Context context;
    private final List<Data> dataList;
    private final UserData userData = DatabaseManager.userData; 
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    // Declared Typeface Global as to prevent repeated call from ViewHolder
    private static Typeface typefaceB;
    private static Typeface typefaceR;
    private static int id; // selector | color Resource ID

    static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView tv1;
        public TextView tv2;
        public TextView tv3;
        public ImageView iv1;

        private void setView() {
            tv1.setTypeface(typefaceB);
            tv2.setTypeface(typefaceR);
            iv1.setBackgroundResource(id);
            tv1.setBackgroundResource(id);
            tv2.setBackgroundResource(id);
            tv3.setBackgroundResource(id);
            tv2.setTextSize(18);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3D3D3D"));
            tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3D3D3D"));
            tv3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3D3D3D"));
        }

    }

    public SomeAdapter(Context context, final List<Data> dataList) {
        objectCounter++;
        System.out.println("SomeAdapter " + objectCounter) ;
        int user = Login.getUserId();
        this.id = userData.getUserLastColor(user); 
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.typefaceB = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.context.getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf");
        this.typefaceR = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.context.getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoSlab-Regular.ttf");
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dataList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return dataList.get(position).get_some_id();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Data data = dataList.get(position);
        if(convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            viewHolder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            viewHolder.iv1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
            viewHolder.setView();
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.tv1.setText("Text 1");
        viewHolder.tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml("Text 2"));
        if (data.updated_time != null && !data.updated_time.isEmpty()) {
            viewHolder.tv3.setText(UtilFunction.formateDate(
                    "MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm aa",
                    UtilFunction.gmtToLocal(data.updated_time)));
        } else {
            viewHolder.tv3.setText(UtilFunction.formateDate(
                    "MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm aa",
                    UtilFunction.gmtToLocal(data.created_time)));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

---

**LOgCat**

```
10-08 16:22:23.328: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 253K, 11% free 8003K/8903K, paused 18ms+3ms, total 45ms
10-08 16:22:23.453: I/Choreographer(13167): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-08 16:22:31.929: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 240K, 10% free 8195K/9095K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 37ms
10-08 16:22:36.179: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 439K, 12% free 8219K/9287K, paused 3ms+15ms, total 55ms
10-08 16:22:40.695: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 423K, 12% free 8203K/9287K, paused 13ms+5ms, total 46ms
10-08 16:22:42.695: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 438K, 12% free 8213K/9287K, paused 13ms+5ms, total 47ms
10-08 16:22:43.515: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 423K, 12% free 8223K/9287K, paused 23ms+5ms, total 67ms
10-08 16:22:54.921: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 433K, 12% free 8212K/9287K, paused 13ms+6ms, total 51ms
10-08 16:22:55.421: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 12% free 8217K/9287K, paused 13ms+5ms, total 58ms
10-08 16:22:56.367: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 422K, 12% free 8217K/9287K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 32ms
10-08 16:22:56.898: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 446K, 12% free 8219K/9287K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 32ms
10-08 16:22:57.500: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 441K, 12% free 8213K/9287K, paused 13ms+5ms, total 52ms
10-08 16:22:58.851: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 416K, 12% free 8217K/9287K, paused 16ms+5ms, total 58ms
10-08 16:22:59.398: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 453K, 12% free 8220K/9287K, paused 2ms+14ms, total 45ms
10-08 16:22:59.750: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 12% free 8217K/9287K, paused 16ms+5ms, total 58ms
10-08 16:23:00.156: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 440K, 12% free 8220K/9287K, paused 13ms+15ms, total 67ms
10-08 16:23:00.671: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 439K, 12% free 8225K/9287K, paused 12ms+14ms, total 50ms
10-08 16:23:01.000: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 442K, 12% free 8206K/9287K, paused 12ms+15ms, total 50ms
10-08 16:23:01.796: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 423K, 12% free 8220K/9287K, paused 12ms+17ms, total 66ms
10-08 16:23:02.851: D/dalvikvm(13167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 422K, 12% free 8208K/9287K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 46ms
```

Thanks for your Time...